# How to store the checkbox state after user leave app Android Studio

Tags: java

I would like to store the checkbox state in AlertDialog even the user leave the app.

How Can I do that?

I tried through SharedPreferences but it can not get it working.

```java
private AlertDialog showAlertDialog() {

        ArrayList<Integer> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Selecione o dia");
        String[] days = {"Domingo","Segunda-Feira","Terça-Feira","Quarta-Feira","Quinta-Feira",
        "Sexta-Feira","Sabado"};
        boolean[] checkedItems = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
        alertDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(days, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i, boolean isChecked) {
            
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dia(s) registrado(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alert.show();
        return alertDialog.create();

                }
```

Comment: hi see approach below and appreciate if you can share with us why sharedpreferences did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no part to save user's selections in your codes, so not clear how you tried saving it in SharedPreferences.

You can try this :

1. When user clicks `Ok`, make a string which contains user's selections and save it in SharedPreferences.

   ```
   alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           String checkedDays = "";
           for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i ++) {
               if (checkedItems[i]) {
                   checkedDays += days[i] + ",";
               }
           }

           getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE)
                   .edit()
                   .putString("Days", checkedDays)
                   .apply();

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dia(s) registrado(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
   });
   ```
2. Read pre-saved selections before showing `AlertDialog`

   ```
   String[] days = {"Domingo","Segunda-Feira","Terça-Feira","Quarta-Feira","Quinta-Feira",
           "Sexta-Feira","Sabado"};
   boolean[] checkedItems = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

   SharedPreferences  preferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
   String checkedDays = preferences.getString("Days", "");
   for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i ++) {
       if (checkedDays.contains(days[i])) {
           checkedItems[i] = true;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank You for your feedback TengFei Li. Your advice works properly in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) why it did not work on your end ?

To write to a shared preferences file, create a SharedPreferences.Editor by calling edit() on your SharedPreferences.

**Note**: You can edit shared preferences in a more secure way by calling the edit() method on an EncryptedSharedPreferences object instead of on a SharedPreferences object. To learn more, see the guide on how to work with data more securely.

Here is generic shared preferences snippet:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
editor.apply();
```

Check the code in the link below and adapt your logic to boolean and checkboxes:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm